# Insert multiple checkbox value in PHP + AJAX

Tags: php

I'm trying to insert multiple checkboxes value in to database using ajax but i don't know what can I do for this method. i tried it with these codes.

```
        <h3 class="page-header">International Language</h3>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="">Chinese</label>
                        <div class="col-md-7">
                          <div class="checkbox checkbox-inline">
                            <label>
                              <input type="checkbox" id="chinese" name="chk[]" value="chinees">
                            </label>
                          </div>
                         </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="">English</label>
                        <div class="col-md-7">
                          <div class="checkbox checkbox-inline">
                            <label>
                              <input type="checkbox" id="english" name="chk[]" value="english">
                            </label>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="">English, Welsh</label>
                        <div class="col-md-7">
                          <div class="checkbox checkbox-inline">
                            <label>
                              <input type="checkbox" id="englishwelsh" name="chk[]" value="englishwelsh">
                            </label>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="">Estonian</label>
                        <div class="col-md-7">
                          <div class="checkbox checkbox-inline">
                            <label>
                              <input type="checkbox" id="estonian" name="chk[]" value="estonian">
                            </label>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="">French</label>
                        <div class="col-md-7">
                          <div class="checkbox checkbox-inline">
                            <label>
                              <input type="checkbox" id="french" name="chk[]" value="frnch">
                            </label>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="">Greek</label>
                        <div class="col-md-7">
                          <div class="checkbox checkbox-inline">
                            <label>
                              <input type="checkbox" id="greek" name="chk[]" value="greek">
                            </label>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="">Latvia</label>
                        <div class="col-md-7">
                          <div class="checkbox checkbox-inline">
                            <label>
                              <input type="checkbox" id="latvia" name="chk[]" value="latvia">
                            </label>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="">Malay</label>
                        <div class="col-md-7">
                          <div class="checkbox checkbox-inline">
                            <label>
                              <input type="checkbox" id="malay" name="chk[]" value="malay">
                            </label>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="">Maltese</label>
                        <div class="col-md-7">
                          <div class="checkbox checkbox-inline">
                            <label>
                              <input type="checkbox" id="maltese" name="chk[]" value="maltese">
                            </label>
                          </div>

                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="">Swedish</label>
                        <div class="col-md-7">
                          <div class="checkbox checkbox-inline">
                            <label>
                              <input type="checkbox" id="swedish" name="chk[]" value="swedish">
                            </label>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>



    $('#btn_ielts_assesment_next').click(function()
        {   
            var id =$("#hlast_id").val();
            var joboffered=$('#joboffered').val();
            var givenielts=$('#givenielts').val();
            var ieltsband=$('#ieltsband').val();
            var ieltspassingyear=$('#ieltspassingyear').val();
            var chiness=$('#chinese').val();
            var english=$('#english').val();
            var englishwelsh=$('#englishwelsh').val();
            var estonian=$('#estonian').val();
            var french=$('#french').val();
            var greek=$('#greek').val();
            var latvia=$('#latvia').val();
            var malay=$('#malay').val();
            var maltese=$('#maltese').val();
            var swedish=$('#swedish').val();
            $.post('<?php echo SERVER_ADMIN_URL;?>ajax/ielts_ajax.php',{action:"btn_ielts_assesment_next",hlast_id:id,                                          joboffered:joboffered,givenielts:givenielts,ieltsband:ieltsband,ieltspassingyear:ieltspassingyear,chiness:chiness,
            english:english,englishwelsh:englishwelsh,estonian:estonian,french:french,greek:greek,latvia:latvia,malay:malay,maltese:maltese        ,swedish:swedish},function(data)
            {

            });
        });

<php>

<?php
if($_POST['action'] == 'btn_ielts_assesment_next'){
$table='assessment';
//$lang=();
$language=implode(",");
$set2=array(
            'joboffered'=>$_POST['joboffered'],
            'givenielts'=>$_POST['givenielts'],
            'ieltsband'=>$_POST['ieltsband'],
            'ieltspassingyear' => $_POST['ieltspassingyear'],
            'languageknown'=>$language);
            $main_where=array('id'=>$_POST['hlast_id']);
            $obj_conn->Update($table,$set2,$main_where, $exclude = '');


}


?><!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

can you help me out ? it's not working. thanks in advance!

Comment: There are so many ways this can go wrong. Did you try debuging it?

Comment: they're just strings. you insert them into a db like any other string, with `INSERT` queries and appropriate [sql injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) avoidance methods.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a very long and cumbersome way to get values. Try the following way to fetch values when using checkboxes.

```
var selected = new Array();
$('#checkboxes input:checked').each(function() {
    selected.push($(this).attr('name'));
});
```

And use can use this array to send values.

But as I see your HTML, you wouldn't need to get individual variables at all, as all the checkboxes have the name as "chk[]", which posts the data as an array. You can submit the form directly, as the all the checked arrays will be available as:

```
$values = $_GET['chk'];
echo '<pre>';print_r($values);echo '</pre>';
```

It should give a result of the type (note only checked checkbox values will be available).

```
array(1=>'greek',2=>'french') etc.
```

You can then use [foreach](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop to manage the values.